# Why isn't getSelectedItem() on JComboBox generic?

Tags: java, swing, generics, jcombobox, java-7

JCombobox in Java 7 has been updated to use generics - I always thought it was a bit of an oversight that it didn't already so I was pleased to see this change.

However, when attempting to use JCombobox in this way, I realised that the methods I expected to use these generic types [still just return `Object.`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29)

Why on earth is this? It seems like a silly design decision to me. I realise the underlying [ListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) has a generic `getElementAt()` method so I'll use that instead - but it's a bit of a roundabout way of doing something that appears like it could have been changed on JComboBox itself.

Comment: maybe http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2266782&tstart=0 +1 for Java7

Comment: @mKorbel Perhaps I'm missing something, but what part of the thread explains it?

Comment: in APIs I can't see changes between Java6 and Java7 for that http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem%28java.lang.Object%29 , nor for http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I suppose you refer to `getSelectedItem()`?

The reason is that if the combo box is editable, the selected item is not necessarily contained in the backing model and not constrained to the generic type. E.g. if you have an editable `JComboBox<Integer>` with the model [1, 2, 3], you can still type "foo" in the component and `getSelectedItem()` will return the String "foo" and not an object of type Integer.

If the combo box is not editable, you can always defer to `cb.getItemAt(cb.getSelectedIndex())` to achieve type safety. If nothing is selected this will return `null`, which is the same behaviour as `getSelectedItem()`.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense - after a memory lapse I forgot about the editable side of JComboBoxes. Most probably because none of them are editable in my application! The method you describe there is what I have been using instead - it seemed like a roundabout way of doing it but now I see why.

Comment: You don't need to be sure an item is selected. If `getItemAt` is given an invalid value (e.g. -1), it returns `null`. This is the same behaviour as `getSelectedItem()` if nothing is selected.

Comment: @DuncanJones: You are right. Without checking, I assumed that getItemAt would throw an IllegalArgumentException, IndexArrayOutOfBoundsException or something like that if invoked with an invalid index.

Comment: @jarnbjo It's definitely unusual behaviour. I would add a comment to my code if I were ever to rely on it.

Comment: If I had an editable combo box that I wanted to constrain to <Integer>, I think that it's reasonable to expect that I can only type in a custom value if it's a valid integer. So I would have preferred them to give us some kind of convertor interface to convert the string to and from the types in the combo box. But for some reason, whoever designed the API wasn't fond of type safety. They didn't update JFormattedTextField either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a type-safe version:

```
public static <T> T getSelectedItem(JComboBox<T> comboBox)
{
    int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
    return comboBox.getItemAt(index);
}
```